# Make feh notice newly plugged-in monitor for image scaling

Tags: multi-monitor, wallpaper, feh

I use my laptop with multiple monitor, I want `feh` to understand that a new monitor has plugged in and scale wallpaper image accordingly.

I use the following code, but when a new monitor is plugged in, `feh` tiles the last wallpaper on all monitors.

```
 feh --bg-scale ~/Pictures/wallpaper/example.jpg
```